# Неочень / не очень

Tags: орфография

Как правильно? Дело в том, что здесь же то можно заменить это слово словом *плохо/плохой*.

1. Картина, которую ты сделала, не очень / неочень.
2. Я чувстую себя не очень / неочень.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Картина, которую ты сделала, не очень***;

***Я чувстую себя не очень***.

Да, можно заменить похожими наречиями — вы уже указали какими. Но в любом случае слово *неочень* выглядит так себе, к тому же такого слова в принципе не существует. Писать слитно — грубая ошибка.

Comment: Перед *какими* – запятая.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Нет, не нужна.

Comment: Точно! Простите за то, что забыл это правило!